# V-for with an array inside it

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm iterating through a JSON array, but have problems with getting data from another array within it.

```
{
  "someData": [
     {
        "name": "a Name of some kind",
           "contactInfo": [
           {
              "phone": "88888888",
              "address": "Heaven, 666"
           }
     }
  ]
}
```

But I can't wrap my head around getting both name and phone in this data as an example.

I'd assume

```
<li v-for="(data, index) in importedData.someData" :key="index">
   {{data.name}}
   {{data.contactInfo.phone}}
</li>
```

or similar would get it, but I simply get the object instead.

Comment: just do another v-for for `phone` i.e. `<div v-for="infos in data.contactInfo"> {{ info.phone}} </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contactInfo` is an array, not an object, you need to access the first element most likely.

```
<li v-for="(data, index) in importedData.someData" :key="index">
   {{data.name}}
   {{data.contactInfo[0].phone}}
</li>
```

If you want to get all phone numbers, you should use another `v-for`

```
<li v-for="(data, index) in importedData.someData" :key="index">
   {{data.name}}
   <span v-for="(contactInfo, ciIndex) in data.contactInfo">
    {{contactInfo.phone}}
   </span>
</li>
```

Comment: ARF. I tried this with a <li> but thought I got a vue-error. But it turned out to just be HTML xD Thanks a lot!
PS: Will accept in 5 mins